# How can I use nerdtree over SSH?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I work alot over SSH using vim, when I use Nerdtree on my local machine , it looks as expected:

[image]

However when I use vim over SSH, it looks like this (e.g. not working ... really...)
[image: NerdTreeOverSSH]

Any ideas how I can solve this little problem, and concentrate on programming?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim - nerdtree suddenly broke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927217/vim-nerdtree-suddenly-broke)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found a solution:

[vim - nerdtree suddenly broke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927217/vim-nerdtree-suddenly-broke)

The locale of my clients and intenally in the company is German, but my locale on my own machine is English. Hence, the problem is only appearing when I use SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Use utf-8 encoding and everything will be good.

`set encoding=utf-8`